# InversifyJS: Inject a specific concretion from a multi-inject definition

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, inversifyjs

Let's assume I use multi-injection in InversifyJS like in the [official example](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/multi_injection.md):

```
container.bind<Ninja>("Ninja").to(Ninja);
container.bind<Weapon>("Weapon").to(Katana);
container.bind<Weapon>("Weapon").to(Shuriken);
```

Is it possible to inject a specific concretion from the bound concretions?
E.g. I would like to explicitly inject the Katana concretion, how would I do this? I don't want to use multi-inject and iterate over/access the array.
In my case I need the multi-injection in one place, and the single-injection in another place.

This does not work as it gives an ambiguous definition error:

```
@inject("Weapon") private weapon: Katana
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [named bindings](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/named_bindings.md).
Or [tagged bindings](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/tagged_bindings.md). Also [default targets](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/default_targets.md).

```
container.bind<Weapon>("Weapon").to(Katana).whenTargetNamed("strong");
container.bind<Weapon>("Weapon").to(Shuriken).whenTargetNamed("weak");

@inject("Weapon") @named("strong") katana: Weapon,
@inject("Weapon") @named("weak") shuriken: Weapon
```